# how to check all checkboxes by rows in a table using jquery?

Tags: jquery

how to check all rows in jquery? having a hard time solving it here

it find inside the **tbody -> 2nd td -> input:checkbox**

I only know how to checkbox single, `$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);` 
but each of rows and looping, I am having a hardtime. can give me some tips?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScCrj.png)

Comment: what are you trying to ask...???

Comment: Describe your problem and what you trying to achieve - result

Answer (score 0):

To make all `checkboxes` checked you can use this code:

```
$('button').on("click", function(){
    $("table input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
        $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
        //When you want to uncheck
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Hope this will help understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Find all checkbox inside the table and change the checked status When the `selectAll` checkbox is clicked which is in the first row.

```js
$('#selectAll').change(function() {
  var checkboxes = $(this).closest('table').find(':checkbox');
  checkboxes.prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="bs-example">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Row</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" /></td>
                <td>Kent</td>
                <td>clarkkent@mail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" /></td>
                <td>Carter</td>
                <td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" /></td>
                <td>Parker</td>
                <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" /></td>
                <td>Rtyer</td>
                <td>yuioo@mail.com</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class"my-checkbox" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class"my-checkbox" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class"my-checkbox" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class"my-checkbox" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button>Click ME</button>
```

If your inputs checkbox are getting generated dynamically please use prop to check and uncheck the checkboxes.